# How to Authenticate the user with a URL?

Tags: xml, ipad, url, authentication

For the first time I am working with Webservices, I have  a URL. i have to post my Login ID and Password to that URL so that I can get somae xml format back to me.

Please suggest me with an example.

Thanks in Advance,
Rizwan.

Comment: this is done by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`You can use ASIHTTPRequest for the same as follows`.

```
NSString *userName = @"yourUserName";
NSString *password = @"yourPassword";

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostValue:userName forKey:@"UserName"];
[request setPostValue:password forKey:@"Password"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Here we have set delegate to self so there are 2 delegate methods to be implemented as follows.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Fetch your xml response here and parse it.
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

This is simple methods you can do a lot with ASIHTTPRequest. For detailed information visit [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).